# driver.getTitle() returns "WebDriver" string everytime for different webpages

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium2

I am beginner in learning selenium. My code is like this:

```
driver.get("http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
String T = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(T);
```

Instead of the actual page title, it always displays "WebDriver" as output on the console.
I am using Internet Explorer as a driver. I tried with different URLs but every time same result.

Comment: You need to wait for the page to load, to confirm this theory add a sleep between your driver.get and the get title statement, or better yet add a wait for page to load before grabbing the title.

Comment: that worked pefectly fine.
as you said :"I think u r using Selenium in an organization where all websites are firewalled except ur organizational websites, web apps that are y u r getting WebDriver as a return value. Please try with your organizational websites web app or timesheets etc.., with gettitle()".
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct I think u r using Selenium in an organization where all websites are firewalled except ur organizational websites, web apps that are y u r getting WebDriver as a return value.
Please try with your organizational websites web app or timesheets etc.., with gettitle(), it will definitely fetch you the title of the currently opened website.

If the issue still persists please let us know.